# Grab exact date without timezone interfering with XMLGregorianCalendar in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I have a `XMLGregorianCalendar` that I would like to convert to a Java `Date` object, but when I try to covert this:

```
2013-11-19T00:00:00-00:00
```

I always get a date with the value a day behind.

```
Mon Nov 18 17:00:00 MST 2013
```

I just want a date object containing `11/19/2013`.

Comment: Just a heads up I dont have a way to modify the XmlGregorianType.

Comment: The value isn't a day behind. It's the exact same moment in time... `2013-11-19T00:00:00-00:00` is midnight UTC, which is 5PM Mountain Standard Time the day before in your timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this,

```
Date startDate = new Date(request.getStartTime().getYear(), request.getStartTime().getMonth(), request.getStartTime().getDay(), 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

As commented above, the result you're getting is right - it's the same moment in time. Midnight UTC is 5PM MST the day before. Perhaps you should look into why your time is in "-00:00" instead of "-07:00" (MST)... but in the meanwhile, I suppose you could try this:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-11-19T00:00:00-00:00");

    Calendar c = xcal.toGregorianCalendar();
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Date d = c.getTime();
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

prints out `Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 EST 2013`, and will work for other times of day, not just midnight.